# Get PHAsset information fast?

Tags: ios, xcode, optimization, metadata, fileinfo

I have a method which retrieves information about a PHAsset, and it works, but when it comes to reading information of hundreds of assets it can be quite slow.

What is the best way to read information about an asset such as filesize and meta-data?

My current code is:

```
- (void) getAssetInfo: (NSUInteger*) assetIndex {
    NSNumber *_assetIndex = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger: assetIndex];

    PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions;
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = @[ [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES], ];
    PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithOptions:fetchOptions];

    PHAsset *asset = [fetchResult objectAtIndex: assetIndex];

    PHImageManager *imageManager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];
    PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc]init];
    options.synchronous = YES;
    options.version = PHImageRequestOptionsVersionCurrent;


    [asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:options
                               completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {

                                   NSString *fileInfo;

                                   NSString *assetURL = nil;

                                   if (contentEditingInput.avAsset != nil){

                                       AVURLAsset *avurlasset_ = (AVURLAsset*) contentEditingInput.avAsset;
                                       assetURL = [avurlasset_.URL absoluteString];

                                   } else {
                                       assetURL = [contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL absoluteString];
                                   }

                                   if (assetURL != nil){
                                       uint64_t fileSize;

                                       NSString *filePathFull = [assetURL substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(7, [assetURL length] - 7)];

                                       NSFileManager * filemanager = [[NSFileManager alloc]init];
                                       if([filemanager fileExistsAtPath:filePathFull]){
                                           fileSize = [[filemanager attributesOfItemAtPath:filePathFull error:nil] fileSize];
                                       }


                                       NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                                       [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy,MM,dd,HH,mm,ss"];

                                       NSArray *assembled_FI = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                                (NSNumber*) _assetIndex,
                                                                assetURL,
                                                                assetURL.lastPathComponent,
                                                                (NSNumber*)[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong: fileSize],
                                                                (NSString*) [dateFormatter stringFromDate:asset.creationDate],
                                                                nil];
                                }
                               }];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small library for Swift 3 recently added to GitHub called AssetManager.

It simplifies the access to assets and allows for very fast data extraction.

The link to AssetManager can be found here: https://github.com/aidv/AssetManager